# how to find external links in article in joomla 2.5 plugin

Tags: plugins, joomla, hyperlink, find

I am creating a plugin in joomla 2.5 for externallinks

I want find external links and and add some text before that.

like these:

```
http://domain.com/new => redirect.php?url=http://domain.com/new
```

or:

```
www.domain.com/new => redirect.php?url=www.domain.com/new
```

or:

```
domain.com/new => redirect.php?url=www.domain.com/new
```

i can do all steps but i cant find external links.
please help me

Comment: Your plugin should run after the content has loaded and you should search the html for external links. Either by using regex (not recommended) or by searching for any <a> element and checking the href value

Answer (score 0):

The way i would do it is by using js which you can add to a template and not bother with a plugin. The js script should go through all the "a" DOM elements and check if the href is an external link. If so modify the href value.

[Fastest way to detect external URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238351/fastest-way-to-detect-external-urls)