# How to have all external links on my website raise a confirm

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to have all external links on my website raise a confirm saying "You are being redirected to an external site." I know how to write the JS to check for if a link is external and how to raise the confirm, but is there a way I can apply this to every link in my site without going through individually? The links will always have the format `<a href=URL> Link </a>`. An angular script would check if the `URL` subdomain is the same as my site, and if not it will add `onclick=return confirm('You will now be redirected to an exteral site')` and `target="_blank"` to the link HTML.

Comment: Yes, what have you tried?

Comment: @Luca I'm really not sure where to begin. I've tried googling, but haven't found anything applicable yet.

Comment: As it is right now, I think your question may be too broad.  I think your next step is to define a context of places where you want to protect users.  There are a **lot** of ways to change pages.  You can control some, wrapping `<a>` clicks for example, but it might get irritating if your footer links keep triggering the warning.  Is your site user content based?  Do you only want to warn about those?  Are users limited to only `<a>`s in posts?  What is the context?

Comment: @zero298 I've updated with a bit more information.

Comment: If the links that you want to trigger the warning have that directive, then what isn't working?  Do you want to extend this protection to links that don't have that directive?

Comment: @zero298 Yes, I want this to extend to all links in my site. It is quite large and would be a pain to go through and edit every single one. This would also make adding new external links a bit easier.

Comment: You'd have to write a directive to intercept every anchor and evaluate its URL to determine whether it's external.

Comment: That would be nice to have something like `document.querySelectorAll('a').filter(a => isExternal(a.src)).forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', warnTheyAreLeaving))`. I wasn't much inspired for the last function name but you would :
Select All links
Filter them if they are external (isExternal would check if the src attribute of a tags have a different domain name than your)
and add an event listener to each of them on click, warn them they are leaving.

I have absolutely no idea about how to implement that in angular though

Comment: I have never understood why people think that this is a good idea unless your goal is to encourage your visitors to never return to your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It can be achieved by the regex matching.
2. Instead of adding multiple event listeners, single event listener can be added on the `document` object and detect the external links as follows. It will give more efficiency.

For reference, [Handling events for multiple elements in a single listener](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)

```js
var regexp = /https?:\/\/(www.){0,1}((?:[\w\d-]+\.)+[\w\d]{2,})/i;
function isExternal(url)
{
    return regexp.exec(location.href)[2] !== regexp.exec(url)[2];
}

document.addEventListener("click",function(){
    if(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase()==="a")
    {
        if(isExternal(event.target.href))
        {
            if(confirm("Redirecting to an external site...."))
            {
                console.log("Going to external site...");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Internal URL Clicked.")
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">External Site 1</a> - https://www.google.com<br>
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">External Site 2</a> - https://www.stackoverflow.com<br>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">External Site 3</a> - http://www.facebook.com (Using HTTP)<br>
<a href="http://www.stacksnippets.net" target="_blank">Internal Site (Using HTTP)</a> - http://www.stacksnippets.net<br>
<a href="http://stacksnippets.net" target="_blank">Internal Site (without www.)</a> - http://stacksnippets.net<br>
<a href="/path/to/something" target="_blank">Internal reference</a> - /path/to/something (Internal reference)<br>
```

Thanks @pseudosavant for the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238351/fastest-way-to-detect-external-urls).

Though @Luca's answer works, the `hostname` is not supported in IE, Safari and Opera. [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hostname) for reference.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using my own logic instead of your regex, but it worked. How would I also add `target="blank"` if the user does confirm he or she wants to leave?

Comment: Couldn’t get you. You mean if the user confirms, you want to direct the user to another page in a new tab ?

Comment: Yes. Filler filler

Comment: It already does, right ? Its target=“_blank” (with an underscore).

Comment: I would like to be able to not have to specify in the original html

Answer (score 2):

As you already said, this can be achieved by using `confirm` onclick, you can easily add an EventListener to all `a` Elements that are external (`l.hostname !== location.hostname`) in your page and only redirect after the user accepts the message, just like so:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a")).filter(l => l.hostname !== location.hostname).forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", evtL));

function evtL(e) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to leave the page?")) {
      return; //redirect
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false; //don't redirect
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="/foo/bar">internal</a>
<a href="https://example.com">external</a>

<a href="https://stacksnippets.net/js">also internal</a>
```

Comment: I was writing my comment at the same time you were posting you're answer so I couldn't see it. Why not filtering the result of the querySelectorAll so not all links have an eventListener, but only the ones who need to have one ?

Comment: You're right, that would be more efficient, thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Edited my post!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Angular.js, I would recommend taking a look at how they work with `<a>` since they **already** have a directive applied to all `<a>` to make `ngHref` work.  The source would be here: [`<a>` directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/a.js).

The basic idea is to put the logic that you use to change the `href` to the warning or display a modal or whatever in the `element.on('click', function(event) {...})`.

Because Angular.js already defined an `<a>` directive, you *may* need to fiddle with the [`priority`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-priority-) of your directive so that you don't accidentally break the way Angular fiddles with `<a>`.

The directive would look something like this:

```
// Logic that dictactes whether the URL should show a warning
function isSuspectUrl(l) {
    return false;
}

const app = angular
    .module("aWarn", [])
    .directive("a", function() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            compile: function(el, attr) {
                element.on("click", function(e) {
                    if (isSuspectUrl(attr.href)) {
                        // Logic that would display a warning
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**2021 version**

- es2015+
- Works with SPA
- Handles local links that look external
- Subdomains support

```js
const baseUrl = window.location.origin;
const absoluteUrlRegex = new RegExp('^(?:[a-z]+:)?//', 'i');

const isAbsoluteUrl = (url) => absoluteUrlRegex.test(url);
const isLocalUrl = (url) => url.startsWith(baseUrl) || !isAbsoluteUrl(url);

// https://gist.github.com/ -> github.com
// https://stackoverflow.com/ -> stackoverflow.com
const getDomain = (url) => {
    const urlInstance = new URL(url);
    const dividedUrl = urlInstance.hostname.split('.');
    const urlDomainsCount = dividedUrl.length;
    return urlDomainsCount === 2
        ? urlInstance.hostname
        : `${dividedUrl[urlDomainsCount - 2]}.${dividedUrl[urlDomainsCount - 1]}`;
};

// example whitelist
const whitelist = [
    'twitter.com',
    'github.com',
];

// url has same domain or whitelisted
const isWhitelistedUrl = (url) => {
    const domain = getDomain(url);
    return domain === window.location.hostname || whitelist.includes(domain);
};

// bind listener
const confirmExternalLinks = (confirmationFn) => {
    document.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
        const linkElement = e.target.closest('a');
        if (!linkElement) return;
        const link = linkElement.getAttribute('href');
        if (isLocalUrl(link) || isWhitelistedUrl(link)) return;
        e.preventDefault();
        const confirmation = await confirmationFn(link);
        if (confirmation) window.open(link);
    });
};

// tip: replace confirmationFn with your custom handler which returns Promise
confirmExternalLinks((link) => confirm(`Proceed to ${link}?`));
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href="https://stacksnippets.net/">https://stacksnippets.net/</a>  is local for this snippet iframe
<br>
<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/">https://twitter.com/</a> is whitelisted
<br>
<a target="_blank" href="https://developer.mozilla.org/">https://developer.mozilla.org/</a>  is external
```