# .load() on an iFrame and FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to attach an event handler `.load()` to an iFrame to take action once an iFrame is loaded.

I have a loading dial that appears on page load then on `.load()` it hides the loading dial.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in FireFox for invalid URLs (like `http://example/`). For some reason, all browsers still fire the `.load()` except for FireFox.

This is causing issues by keeping the loading dial on screen.

Is there workaround to make the `.load()` event fire in FireFox on invalid URLs?

Comment: `$.load` will never work with external URLs.

Comment: So how can I remove my loading dial for invalid URLs? The user is changing the URL themselves for the iFrame.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910946/test-if-links-are-external-with-jquery-javascript   or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238351/fastest-way-to-detect-external-urls

Comment: Try `if (iframe.readyState == "complete"){ // Do your stuff}`

Comment: @senyorToni won't I have to loop that though?

Comment: @Alvaro that doesn't help me in the slightest

Comment: @Jamesking56 why not. You just have to check if the link is external or not and add a condition to show your dialog or not.