# Conditioning in jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm totally new to jQuery and I'm trying to write a simple script in to say I want to add an pdf.png image to all the links that end with .pdf and also a external link that starts with http but I for PDF files on different hosts, I want the script to only add the pdf image (I have a css file for adding the images) like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[href$='.pdf']").addClass('pdf');
    $("a[href^='http']a[href$!='.pdf']").addClass('external');   
});
```

but it actually shows the external image when the path starts with http and ends with .pdf (so it's doing the opposite). Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: what do you mean by `add an pdf.png image to all the links that end with .pdf and also a external link that starts with http but I don't want for PDF files on different hosts,`

Comment: you want to add teh class `pdf` to anchors with target ending with `pdf` and class external to anchors with target starting with `http` but not ending with `http`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will add the class `pdf` to the elements which have `href` ends with `.pdf` but `not` starts with `http`. According to your comment, you just need to add the class `external` to the `elements` which are having `href starts with http` and `not ends with .pdf`. Have a look at the line of code below the commented one to achieve your need.

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[href $= '.pdf']").addClass('pdf');
    //$("a[href^='http']a[href$!='.pdf']").addClass('external');   
    $("a[href^='http']").not("a[href $= '.pdf']").addClass('external');   

});
```

Comment: @ali can you post your sample html.?

Comment: Oh I got it. Your solution is correct but what I needed was a bit different. It works like this: $("a[href$='.pdf']").addClass('pdf');
    $("a[href^='http']").not("a[href$='.pdf']").addClass('external');

Comment: Can I ask you something else? How can I know if a link is an external link in jQuery?

Comment: @ali I hope this will help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910946/test-if-links-are-external-with-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[href^='http']").addClass('external'); 
    $("a[href$='.pdf']").removeClass('external').addClass('pdf');  
});
```