# Jquery External links with else if statement

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, external, addclass

I have this tool that uses both hard and relative links for local pages. (I didn't build it)  I now need to classify external links.  Tried with this but it gets stuck at the 'else if' level.  What am I doing wrong?  Without the 'else if' it mistakenly marks some local links as external, but with it, nothing happens.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var comp = new RegExp(location.host);
    jQuery('a').each(function(){
        if(comp.test(jQuery(this).attr('href'))) {
            jQuery(this).addClass('local');
        }
        else if(jQuery(this)('a[href$="ABC"]')) {
            jQuery(this).addClass('local2');
        }
        else {
        jQuery(this).addClass('external');
    }    
});
```

Comment: you js contains errors, what are you getting in your console?

Answer (score 3):

Your existing code is invalid and should show a console error as the following is not a valid expression:

`jQuery(this)('a[href$="ABC"]')`

As you generally need to identify external links only, and any internal links are treated the same (absolute *or* relative) I have this jQuery selector that will match all the possible external links (including email & file links etc):

```
'a[href*="://"]:not(a[href^="' + window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '"]),a[href^="mailto:"]'
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/qxn8L86a/10/

Simplified version (if your site has no *absolute local links*):

```
$('a[href*="://"],a[href^="mailto:"]').addClass("external");
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/qxn8L86a/8/

To add a class to the local links you can just exclude the external ones:

e.g.

```
$('a').not($('a[href*="://"],a[href^="mailto:"]').addClass("external")).addClass("local");
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/qxn8L86a/9/

Reference (my question) here: [RegEx expression or jQuery selector to NOT match "external" links in href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084627/regex-expression-or-jquery-selector-to-not-match-external-links-in-href)

Comment: why is hashtag external link?

Comment: @Mephiztopheles: Leftover from another project - not needed here so now removed (and `_blank` removed too as this question would consider that local). See the linked question for what that one was doing.