# Method for selecting elements in Sizzle using fully-qualified URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, sizzle

While working on a script recently, I came across a peculiar nuance of [how Sizzle works](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L391) with [the `href` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2639280/451969). Specifically, using an attribute selector on an `href`, Sizzle will use the actual attribute value:

```
// Will not find <a href="index.html">...
$('a[href="http://www.example.com/index.html"]')
```

Sizzle uses [`.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute) instead of [`elem.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement) (or more precisely, `elem['href']`, as [Sizzle does in most cases](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L854)); `elem.href` would provide the fully-qualified URL.

To understand this a bit more, I created a fiddle to [try different forms of URLs](http://jsfiddle.net/RLLZZ/). In the process of testing, I discovered the (obvious) "solution" of [setting the `href` equal to itself](http://jsfiddle.net/Xax3W/):

```
$('a').each(function(){
    this.href = this.href;
});
```

Which, unsurprisingly, updates the element to reflect the fully-qualified URL that `this.href` provides. There are other ways I've found that work (any that update the `href` attribute of an element), but they just port the above approach to other forms, or involve something like [`.filter()` (demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/wYFUN/):

```
var matches = $('a').filter(function(){
    var window_location = 'http://example.com/services.html';
    return window_location == this.href;
});
```

The reason I say this is that doing `el.href = el.href` before selecting is a workaround in a sense (and one I don't think is a great alternative). For instance, running a check on a set of elements to find if any contain a matching link to the current URL (or another URL) is simpler to do if you can:

```
$links.not('[href="' + window.location.href + '"]')
```

Is there a way to do this without having to resort to "updating" the attributes, or writing additional code to manage the check? Is there a way I've overlooked that doesn't involve modifying how Sizzle works **^**?

**^ Note**: Modifying the actual source code would be a (bad) idea compared to just adding an `expression`:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    url: function(elem, i, match){
        return elem.href === match[3];
    }
});

var $matched = $('a:url(http://test.com/index.html)');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yt2RU/

(And as an aside, are there other attributes with similar untypical behavior in Sizzle?)

Comment: It's more efficient (and more legible, IMHO) to just use `.filter()` instead, so if you know it doesn't work like that, just don't use it for this particular case. (And no, I don't think there's any other way. Attribute selector are attribute selectors, not property selectors.)

Comment: minitech, my question is whether I'm overlooking something. I don't know Sizzle well enough to know if I am right or not, or that using `.filter()` would be faster.

Comment: Okay. (I'm pretty sure `filter` is faster though - a simple tag selector like `a` can be optimized to `getElementsByTagName`.)

Comment: @minitech - Also, another reason I asked the question is because when I was looking around for an answer, I couldn't find one about this specific problem I ran into. If this is right (there's no way to get it to work with fully-qualified URLs), that's fine. Hopefully it might help someone else having the same problem I did.

Comment: @minitech - And that's a good point about attribute selectors vs. property selectors. My particular issue was that I needed to block functionality on a menu depending on the `href` value and the URL, so `getElementsByTagName()` wouldn't necessarily replace a selector in that case, unless I'm not understanding the comment.

Comment: Sizzle is consistent with native browser `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` methods.  Updating sizzle won't help for more current browsers which use native methods. http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/Zg2Ve/

Comment: @gilly3 - I've never used those, so that's good to know. A [custom expression](http://jsfiddle.net/yt2RU/) could be added I suppose.

Comment: If you've used jQuery, you've used them, albeit indirectly.  Sizzle is jQuery's fallback selector engine for browsers that don't support `querySelectorAll()` natively - so, really only IE7.

Comment: @gilly3 - Ok, your comment makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: @gilly3 - If either you or minitech want to add an answer with your response, I don't mind deleting my answer and marking of yours as the answer (and an upvote). My answer came from your comments, so I think it's only fair.

Comment: @minitech - If either you or gilly3 want to add an answer with your response, I don't mind deleting my answer and marking of yours as the answer (and an upvote). My answer came from your comments, so I think it's only fair.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Nah. Your answer is original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I've got the answer to this question...

Use either an [`expression`](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/expr/):

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    url: function(elem, i, match){
        return elem.href === match[3];
    }
});

var $matched = jQuery('a:url(http://test.com/index.html)');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yt2RU/

Or, as it was noted in the comments, `$.filter()` could be used:

```
var $matched = $('a').filter(function(){
    if (this.href == 'http://test.com/index.html') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dMuyj/

And that jQuery only falls back to Sizzle if [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) are not available natively, and that both of these work the same as jQuery's selector engine (not surprising).

The sum total is, you either need an expression or a filter if you desire this type of selector, and use `elem.href` for the comparison, not [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute).