# Can't change url in href with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I'm trying to replace a part of url in the middle ('#') with another one, and remove first part of url. Script replaces '#' with no problem but rfuses to remove the first part of url. Am i doing something wrong, or is there another solution for that?

html of it

```
<a class="link_imagelibrary" href="#pink_yellow_flowers.pdf?5612">Download pdf set</a>
```

on condition changes to

```
<a class="imgdownload" href="http://www.picturewall.com/pages/Botanicalhttp://#.com/s/files/1/0183/2687/files/passpink_yellow_flowers.pdf?5612">Download pdf set</a>
```

jquery

```
$(".imgdownload").each(function(){ 
   this.href = this.href.replace('#', 'http://#.com/s/files/1/0183/2687/files/pass');
   this.href = this.href.replace('http://www.#.com/pages/botanical', '');
});
```

It's supposed to happen on condition. Judging that the rest of the script works fine on the condition- looks like the problem is somewhere here

Comment: What kind of URLs are you applying this to?

Comment: What do you mean by what kind of url?

Comment: @user3638287 Show your actual url you are trying to replace and what is your expected result looks like.

Comment: I meant that I need to know what URL you are doing this with. Anyway, try checking the question that was marked as a duplicate, and see if that works. If it doesn't, you should edit your question to be a bit more specific, showing what the problem is, and why that's not answered by the duplicate question.

Comment: added url to the post

Comment: @user3638287 can't you simply do `this.href = 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0183/2687/files/pass'` then, instead of those 2 seperate `.replace()`s?

Comment: no. there are, actually, quite a few of them with that class

Comment: I believe this is related to the [same issue I had with this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222026/method-for-selecting-elements-in-sizzle-using-fully-qualified-urls).

Comment: What is the final url you want?

Comment: http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0183/2687/files/pass-whatever was after #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is not being matched

```
this.href = this.href.replace('http://www.picturewall.com/pages/botanical', '');
```

because it doesn't exist in your href: (**Note the capitalisation of 'Botanical'**)

```
"http://www.picturewall.com/pages/Botanicalhttp://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0183/2687/files/passpink_yellow_flowers.pdf?5612"
```

Comment: I'll be damned... Such a stupid mistake... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The `href` is expanding with `this.href`, so while you have:

```
<a href="#" ...
```

The DOM element's `href` property gets this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/your/page/wherever.php#" ...
```

The easiest way to handle this is to do it differently:

```
$(".imgdownload").each(function(){ 
   this.href = 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0183/2687/files/pass' +
               this.href.split('#').pop();
});
```

Here is a demonstration of the "problem":

```
$('a').each(function ea(){
    console.log(this.href, this.getAttribute('href'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gtr8V/

You'll note that `element.getAttribute('href')` does return the raw `href` attribute value, not the property. You could use this with `.replace()` instead of the `this.href.replace()` you were trying.

Comment: the thing is, that # splits url in 2. I need to keep the part that comes after # (pink_yellow_flowers.pdf?5612 for example), and this solution is going to edit entire url.

Comment: Unless I'm confused, looking at the code in your question, you're doing two steps, the first of which is causing the need for the second (removing the first URL). What I'm proposing is to do one thing (not two) that replaces the need to remove the first URL in a second step.